# Different between Google Speech API and Web Speech API

Tags: webspeech-api, google-speech-api

I am working on web speech recognition.

And I found that Google provide a API which call "Google speech API V2" to developer. But I notice there is a limit on every day to use it.

After that I found there is a native WEB Speech API also can implement the speech recognition. And it just working on google chrome and opera:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=speech-recognition

So 
 1. What is the different  Google Speech API and Web Speech API? Are they have any relations?

2. The speech recognition result json is return from google. Is that the google speech api will be more accurate than web speech api?

Thank you.

Comment: https://speechless.surge.sh   You can also use a tool that i developed that detects if the browser supports native recognition

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [Web Speech API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html) is a W3C supported specification that allows browser vendors to supply a speech recognition engine of their choosing (be it local or cloud-based) that backs an API you can use directly from the browser without having to worry about API limits and the like. You could imagine that Apple might power this with Siri and Microsoft might power this with Cortana. Again, browser vendors could opt to use the built in dictation software in the operating system, but that doesn't seem to currently be the trend. If your trying to perform simple speech synthesis in a browser (e.g. voice commands), this is likely the best path to take, especially as adoption grows.

The [Google Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/) is a cloud-based solution that allows you to use Google's speech software outside of a browser. It also provides broader language support and can transcribe longer audio files. If you have a 20min audio recording you want to transcribe, this would be the path to take. As of the time of this writing, Google charges $0.006 for every 15s recorded after the first hour for this service.

Comment: Are you familiar with issues on a live webserver using the Web Speech API? Locally the Web Speech API works, but after deploying to AWS EC2, I get error `speechSynthesis: error “not allowed”`. I detailed my issues here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45891229/web-mdn-speech-api-speechsynthesis-error-not-allowed

Answer (score 0):

The Web API is REST based API with API key authentication, especially for web pages which needs a a simple feature set.

While Google Speech API basically is a gRPC API with various authentication method. There are lot feature is available when you use gRPC, like authentication, faster calling, and streaming!!!