# Web Speech API vs Google Speech API

Tags: google-chrome, speech-recognition, speech

I've been using [MDN Speech APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/speechSynthesis) (using things like `window.speechSynthesis` and `new SpeechSynthesisUtterance`). Firstly, I thought this API was the same as [Google's Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rest/), but I guess it is not?

Secondly, it's been working great, but there are some challenges I've been facing:

- only available in Chrome and Safari
- voices do seem robotic sometimes
- [transcribed texts are awkward with numerals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45663618/google-chrome-stt-number-transcriptions-as-numerals-for-foreign-locales)

Firstly, I'm curious if Google's Speech API solves these issues. Whas your experience been with Google's Speech API?

- Does the API work across any device? I want to build a game in Unity with Speech. Can I use it within Unity so long as I'm querying the API?
- Is it better at recognizing contexts?

  - spoken `si yo hablo espanol` -> Does not capture `si`
  - spoken `me llamo Dan` -> does not capture proper noun `Dan`
- Does it have less robotic voices?

Thank you!

---

**Note**: I am familiar with the [use cases for both APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32517331/different-between-google-speech-api-and-web-speech-api), I'm looking more for the performance in each of the areas listed above.